# Ace editor doesn't format the data inside the editor div

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have embedded some `JSON` data inside the editor div.

as here  : http://jsfiddle.net/P3TwV/11/

But as shown in the fiddle, the JSON is not being formatted. It simply put the data in one line.

i want the data, that i inputed in single line without any spaces, should get automatically formatted with proper indenting, according to the specified type as here JSON and all the folding and unfolding of the objects inside the editor should get enable.

How do i approach that?

Any answer will help me here. Thank you.

Comment: Over three years too late, but I figured out a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ace doesn't support formatting the code, you can either use [beautify.js](https://github.com/einars/js-beautify/blob/master/js/lib/beautify.js) or browsers built-in json formatter

```
var val = editor.session.getValue()
var o = JSON.parse(val) // may throw if json is malformed
val = JSON.stringify(o, null, 4) // 4 is the indent size
editor.session.setValue(val)
```

Comment: here is the result : http://jsfiddle.net/P3TwV/25/ .. the json data is not shown formatted. only the string is modified inserting /n and /t etc but all in single line. that i dont want.

Comment: I've made a typo, It should have been `val = JSON.stringify(o, null, 4)` not `val = JSON.stringify(val, null, 4)`, fixed now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used [beautify](http://jsbeautifier.org/) and used `js_beautify` function and work done.

Answer (score 0):

As [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743328/a-user) mentioned, you should go with [beautify.js](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify).

I tried including the Ace Beautifier plugin, but the formatting was completely off.

```
// https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/ext-beautify.js
var beautify = ace.require('ace/ext/beautify');

beautify.beautify(editor.getSession());
```

Here is an example of hooking JS Beautifier into your existing Ace Editor.

```js
// Variables
var editor = ace.edit('editor');
var txtAra = document.querySelector('textarea[name="editor"]');
var jsbOpts = {
  indent_size : 2
};

// Setup
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/json");
syncEditor();

// Main Logic
setTimeout(formatCode, 1000); // Format sample JSON after 1 second.

// Functions
function syncEditor() {
  editor.getSession().setValue(txtAra.value);
}
function commitChanges() {
  txtAra.value = editor.getSession().getValue();
}
function formatCode() {
  var session = editor.getSession();
  session.setValue(js_beautify(session.getValue(), jsbOpts));
}
```

```css
.title {
  font-size: 1.67em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#editor {
  height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;
}
textarea[name="editor"] {
  display: none;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/ace.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.6.8/beautify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <div class="title">Ace Editor - JSON Format</div>
  <textarea name="editor">{"glossary": {"title": "example glossary","GlossDiv": {"title": "S","GlossList": {"GlossEntry": {"ID": "SGML","SortAs": "SGML","GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language","Acronym": "SGML","Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986","GlossDef": {"para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.","GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},"GlossSee": "markup"}}}}}</textarea>
  <div id="editor"></div>
</div>
```