# How to format code in ace editor?

Tags: java, javascript, ace-editor

I am using ace editor  as  text editor . I have an issue whenever i save the code(java) from editor it appears to be saved as a single line .It kind of ignores the enter key press.How to fix the problem?

Comment: have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202540/ace-editor-doesnt-format-the-data-inside-the-editor-div

Answer (score 1):

How do you save a code? One possible issue is that your editor is configured to use unix new line characters ('\n') which doesn't not work with some windows programs.
try `value = value.replace(/\r\n?|\n/g, "\r\n")` before saving the value, or `editor.setOption("newLineMode", "windows")`

Comment: i am using mac not windows will still giv it a try